# Solution for black screen after setting the screen brightness cursor to 0

Tags: kubuntu, screen, brightness, monitor

My screen went completely black after I set the screen brightness cursor to 0. I know it's not very smart, but my previous Linux installation had a minimum value which was allowing the screen to still be usable, so old reflex!

Now it is impossible to do anything anymore, and rebooting keeps a fully black screen.

How do I restore the brightness of my screen?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by doing the following:

1. Rebooting in Kubuntu "rescue" mode (I just looked around the different cleaning up possibilities and went looking on the console too to see if I could save a few things).
2. Then I allowed the system to keep booting (it told me that a few devices would not work as usual) and my screen went visible again.
3. I set the brightness cursor to an average position again (even if the screen was not directly sensitive).
4. Then I did a full reboot and things went normal!

Would have saved me a bit of time if I had found a post like that, so here it is!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I also have a solution for this problem. I bumped on this thread accidentally, but you can use the keyboard to change the brightness.

Brightness buttons on many laptops are: <kbd>F11</kbd> (- brightness)/<kbd>F12</kbd> (+ brightness). Depending on your machine and settings, you may need to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button with <kbd>F12</kbd>.

You can also try this **if you can write blindly**:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Write (blindly):

   ```
   xrandr --output `xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " "` --brightness 1
   ```

   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It should set the brightness as 1 from the connected monitor.

Reminding that it is not the best option, but I have solved my issue once doing this. I **hate** writing blindly in a terminal, but if you are a little bit adventurous, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too easy but I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then typed in:

```
reboot
```

The computer came back on with default brightness of 16%.

For a split second it showed a red warning light on the brightness icon in the top panel.

Answer (score 0):

I just shined a flashlight on my screen and then raised the brightness the way I set it down.